# DRUPAL 7.34 Administrar BBDD

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

En la intranet de la empresa, que se la hizo una empresa externa, me gustaría poder acceder a la BBDD para consultar unos datos y poder ejecutar sentencias SQL (si fuese el caso)
El servidor no puedo acceder (Desde windows) a su interface mediante escritorio remoto. Sólo puedo acceder a los archivos mediante ssh con putty o WinSCP.

La web está realizada con Drupal 7.34
PHP ver 5.3.3
Servidor web    Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Sistema de la base de dades MySQL, MariaDB, or equivalent

Desde la intranet, puedo acceder al apartado Menú Administración
https://intranet.web.com/admin/config

Pero no veo cómo acceder a algo parecido a

https://intranet.web.com/admin/phpmyadmin y que me pida usuario y contraseña de la BBDD (que la tengo) y a partir de ahí, administrar y poder ejecutar consultas SQL.

No puedo hacer localhost/phpmyadmin porque estoy haciéndolo desde windows y no tengo forma de acceder al servidor mediante escritorio.

Si me pueden ayudar, por favor para indicarme cómo lo hacen en éstos casos?

Gracias.

Comment: No está muy claro cuál es la base de datos que usas ni el grado de conectividad que hay entre tu máquina y la máquina donde corre esa base de datos pero si tienes conectividad y la BBDD es MySQL, puedes instalar en tu local el MySQL workbench y luego configurar una conexión a esa BBDD. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/ También puedes instalar un Apache y PHPMyAdmin en tu máquina local y configurarlo para que acceda a la BBDD remota.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Puedo conectarme a esa intranet sin problemas. Voy a configurar la conexión que comentas en el workbench, a ve si lo consigo. Gracias

Comment: Relevante saber del usuario que tienes: ¿desde cuáles hosts tiene acceso? y ¿tiene permisos administrativos?.